# How to align a text to justified in Crystal Reports?

Tags: text, crystal-reports, formatting

I have a text like below.

```
ABC agrees to provide programming services for ABI ‎("‎CLIENT‎") ‎as described below under
"‎Programming Services‎" ‎for <u>which CLIENT is to pay</u> a rate described in Attachment A.
```

This text should be underlined and the whole text should be justified. I have used a formula field with `TextInterpretation` as `HTMLText`. The text is underlined, but it's not justified correctly.

I tried to use `TextObject`, it's justified but the required text is not underlined. Please show me how to both underline and justify text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**solution for Justify in crystal report with visual studio 2010** 
**Right click on your Text Object
In format Editer

Paragraph -> Horizontal Alignment -> Alignment -> Justified**

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the formula (setting HTML Text in Text Interpretation) with html tags. For example:

```
'<div align="justify">El nombre es <b>primordial</b> de saber...</div>'
```

I do it because I need a formula with some words in bold and justified text.

Comment: I spent three days trying to find a solution to a formula field filled from database and to be displayed as HTML Arabic and justified; I have tried multiple solutions and posted a new question on stack overflow but nothing worked ... until I found those 3 small lines that saved my week! Thank you @anpadia

Answer (score 2):

Put your formula into a **Text Object** and double click the text object to edit. Now select the formula, Right Click and click on **Format {@formula_name}**. Then Select **HTML Text** in Text Interpretation. You can see the Text will be justified and  tags will be recognized too.

Check the images below for reference.

[image: Formula_Format]
[image: Text_Format]
And this is the result I got 
[image: Result]
Hope this helps you. Try this and pls get back with your results.

Answer (score 2):

For VS 2017 the allignment configuration is moved to `Common` section

[image]