# Horizontally center text in details section

Tags: crystal-reports, text-align

**Current output:**

```
coloumn1|column2|column3
--------|-------|-------
abc     |      2|      5
abc     |      3|      4
abc     |      4|      3
abc     |      5|      2
abc     |      6|      1
```

**Desired output:**

```
coloumn1|column2|column3
--------|-------|-------
   abc  |   2   |   5
   abc  |   3   |   4
   abc  |   4   |   3
   abc  |   5   |   2
   abc  |   6   |   1
```

How can I horizontally center a field within its column? Format object doesn't seem to have that option.

Comment: You can use a mono-spaced font like Courier font as well.

Answer (score 1):

For this just right click on control -> format. There is setting available for horizontal and vertical. set as you want.

Please refer this :

[How to align a text to justified in Crystal Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740207/how-to-align-a-text-to-justified-in-crystal-reports)